# How to Customize the capture screen border of zxing barcode scanner from ViewFinder

Tags: android, customization, barcode, qr-code, zxing

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_framing_rect_height="220dp"
            app:zxing_framing_rect_width="250dp" />


        <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ViewfinderView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_possible_result_points="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points"
            app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
            app:zxing_viewfinder_laser="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_laser"
            app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_mask" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

I want to customize the capturing area of barcode and i am using the zxing embeded barcode so how shall i make the border of barcode area by my self. I just know that some changes would be don to ViewFinder class but the ViewFinder class is in library in jar library so how could i change it?

I just want to make the customize barcode border

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do something about it ?

Comment: yes i did the customization on scanning screen

Comment: if u are using android studio it would be more easier to do this by just editing the library of zxing that has viewFinder.java class

Comment: solved it yesterday thanks. Using these sample codes. https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/tree/master/zxing-sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set #00000000 as value of app:zxing_viewfinder_mask, and add an ImageView that contain the mask

```
app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="#00000000"
```

Comment: I had to edit the ViewFinder class for color changements

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can override the color in your own colors.xml file 
i.e.
`<color name="viewfinder_border">#00d1cf</color>`