# Change ViewFinder in zxing

Tags: android, zxing

How can I change the viewfinder size, colors and other options when I'm using dependencies `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'` without an access to the zxing files?
I could not find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

to change the color of the ViewFinder.
add these to your project's colors.xml

```
<color name="viewfinder_mask">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="viewfinder_laser">#00FFFFFF</color>
<color name="viewfinder_border">#ffFF4081</color>
```

to make other changes like removing laser from ZXingScannerView's viewfinder
create a class and extend ViewFinderView. Override methods to customize the UI
like so.

```
public class CustomScannerView extends ZXingScannerView {

public CustomScannerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
    return new CustomViewFinderView(context);
}

//make changes in CustomViewFinderView to customise the Viewfinder
//Check ViewFinderView class for more modifications
//to change viewFinder's colours override appropriate values in Colors.xml
class CustomViewFinderView extends ViewFinderView {


    public CustomViewFinderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setSquareViewFinder(true);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        // DEFAULT SQUARE DIMENSION RATIO in ViewFinderView is 0.625
        // get appropriate Dimension ratio otherwise
        float width = displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.625f;
        setBorderLineLength((int)width);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLaser(Canvas canvas) {
        //do nothing for no laser, even remove super call
    }

 }
}
```

to set the viewfinder's rectangle
use

```
super.getFramingRect().set(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the laser only, this can simply be done by disabling the alpha channel animation:

```
barcodeView = (DecoratedBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);

ViewfinderView viewFinder = barcodeView.getViewFinder();
Field scannerAlphaField = null;
try {
    scannerAlphaField = viewFinder.getClass().getDeclaredField("SCANNER_ALPHA");
    scannerAlphaField.setAccessible(true);
    scannerAlphaField.set(viewFinder, new int[1]);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you know of to remove the frame or the camera overaly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via XML

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
      android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:zxing_framing_rect_height="220dp"
      app:zxing_framing_rect_width="250dp" />

<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ViewfinderView
    android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:zxing_possible_result_points="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points"
    app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
    app:zxing_viewfinder_laser="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_laser"
    app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_mask" />
```

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371195/how-to-customize-the-capture-screen-border-of-zxing-barcode-scanner-from-viewfin) (possible duplicate this question), and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852059/zxing-barcode-reader-how-to-make-custom-border-around-capture-screen), if you want to change behavior programmatically.

To access the library features, you need to add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'
}
```

And add camera permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: but how can I install it to get access to its classes? I'm new to Android development.

Comment: @codddeer123 just add dependency `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'` to application module with Gradle. Also you can use the installation guide from [Github project](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner#installation). After that start sync project, then you can use the classes and views from library.

Comment: inside External Libraries -> zxing-1.9? There is only BuildConfig and ZXingScannerView

Comment: @codddeer123 please, check my updated answer. As I said, you have 2 build.gradle files. The 1st one for whole project, the 2nd one for certain module.

Comment: Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'zxing_framing_rect_height' in package 'android' I am getting this error when I am adding zxing_framing_rect_height